# Match a digit in Visual Studio with regular expressions

Tags: visual-studio, regex

How do I match a digit in Visual Studio?

My first guess is `\d`, but it is not working for me.

Second, is there a list of special characters in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MSDN docs for Visual Studio's regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx), it's `:d`.

There's also `:z` which matches one or more digits, i.e. used to match an integer.

And yes, [VS regexes are bizarre](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000633.html).

Answer (score 4):

Here are the Regular Expressions that it recognizes. Read this great article on the [Visual Studio Regular Expressions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000633.html) by Jeff Atwood.

[image]
<sub>(source: [codinghorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/images/visual-studio-2005-find-dialog-builder.png))</sub>

Comment: That's only a partial list. From the docs: "The list of all regular expressions that are valid in Find and Replace operations is longer than can be displayed in the Expression Builder." In particular, that doesn't show :d for digit...

Comment: The screenshot is very helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: The image link is broken (as of 2009-12 because *[Jeff Atwood did not practice what he preaches](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/international-backup-awareness-day.html)*?)

Answer (score 2):

It may work if you try `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming you just need to match literally numbers, you could use a range like **[0-9]+**

Answer (score 1):

There's a little drop down to the right of the find box that will show you the regular expression notation used in the VS find utility. It's the big arrow pointing to the right.

You can use :z for digits (and make sure you have the regex checkbox checked :).

Answer (score 1):

[*Regular Expressions (Visual Studio)*, Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(VS.80).aspx) (MSDN) states that it's `:d`.

Answer (score 0):

How to match a digit depends on the version of Visual Studio<sup>1</sup>:

- `\d` will work in [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) and later. These versions of Visual Studio uses the same syntax as .NET Framework regular expressions.
- `:d` will work in [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) and earlier (Visual Studio .NET 2003, Visual Studio .NET (2002), [Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005), [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008), and [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010))

As for the second question, there is a list of special characters in *[Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)* (for both the new and old syntax).

<sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) *[Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)* (MSDN)</sup>

Comment: Added to keep this question current.

Comment: Uhm ... I've never used a version higher than 08 and I've never had a problem using normal RegEx ... including using `\d` ... Just saying ... I can even show proof soon as I get home. I have a ToolBar app that structures an address book based on A LOT of Regex and every expression is pretty "standard", including use of `\d,\w,\s`