# Regular expressions in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio

I want to find all lines matching a word containing 'if' in a bunch of C++ source files in Visual Studio, so I need to filter out the `if` statements as well as the `#if` preprocessor statements.

The regular expression I'm trying to use is the following: `[^#]*if[^\s]+`

But the results I get include all the `if` statement and `#if` lines.

I have checked the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/812107/198011) and the [documentation on Visual Studio regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) and still don't get to know why the expression I'm using doesn't work as expected.

Is the syntax for Visual Studio regular expressions dialect properly documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\s` isn't the VS shortcut for whitespace, `:b` is (space or tab). That's covered in the docs page you linked to.

Comment: Try `\#`; the `#` has a special meaning in VS regexes (I would have thought it does so only outside of character classes, but who knows). Also, you probably need a `^` anchor at the start, or the regex will match lines with `#if` because the `*` makes the "not-#" part optional. I don't have VS installed, so I can't test it, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Tim. You're right about `\s`. This works: `[^\#]*if[^:b]+`.

Comment: I guess I'm too used (I don't make intensive use of regex, though) to a *NIX regex flavor.

Answer (score 1):

This will match any `if` that is not preceded by a `#` and is not followed by `(`, tweak it to fit your need.

```
~(\#)if~(\()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the `#`?

```
[^\#]*if[^\s]+
```

Comment: Apparently the `#` has no special meaning for regex syntax. I tried it anyway and it didn't work.

Comment: Well, it *does* have special meaning -- see your documentation link, but if you've tried it the problem may be elsewhere, as well.

Comment: Right, thanks. Ì looked at that table but I somehow failed to see the row for '#' :)

Comment: In VS2010 '#' used to mean "Matches one or more occurrences of the preceding expression, and matches as few characters as possible." . It no longer appears to have special significance (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx). Also, braces {} used to group expressions, and \1 would refer to the group. As of VS2015, now it's parens () to group, and $1 to refer.